# singleton на python

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования

Релизовал singleton с Wiki([ссылка на вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)))

Мой код:

```
class SpriteManager(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
             cls.instance = super(SpriteManager, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance

    def __init__(self):

        self.setSprite = set()
```

Каждый раз при вызове **SpriteManager()** вызывается конструктур.
Согласно концепции singleton, инициализация должна проходить один раз при первом вызове.
Как сделать,что бы конструктор вызывался один раз?

Comment: Чем имеющаяся реализация не подходит для вас? Создаётся только один объект. Вам нужно, чтобы при повторном вызове конструктора бросалось исключение? Опишите подробнее требования к поведению.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev , мне нужно получать ссылку на singleton, не вызывая каждый раз конструктор.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
class SpriteManager(object):
    __instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def inst():
        if SpriteManager.__instance == None:
            SpriteManager.__instance = SpriteManager()
        return SpriteManager.__instance

    #single call check
    def __init__(self):
        print("Constructor called!")


a = SpriteManager.inst()
b = SpriteManager.inst()
print(a is b)
```

По выводу видим, что конструктор вызывается только один раз:

```
Constructor called!
True
```

Доступ к синглтону осуществляем через функцию *inst()*, например так:

```
SpriteManager.inst().update()
```

Answer (score 5):

Патерны проектирования - это не кусок кода, это некоторая идея, которую можно реализовать различными способами. Тот же Singleton может быть реализован несколькими способами. Рассмотрим примеры.

*написано на основе http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Singleton.html*

Одна из реализаций - делегировать "одиночку" внутреннему классу:

```
class OnlyOne:
    class __OnlyOne:
        def __init__(self, arg):
            self.val = arg
        def __str__(self):
            return repr(self) + self.val
    instance = None
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if not OnlyOne.instance:
            OnlyOne.instance = OnlyOne.__OnlyOne(arg)
        else:
            OnlyOne.instance.val = arg
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)

x = OnlyOne('sausage')
print(x)
y = OnlyOne('eggs')
print(y)
z = OnlyOne('spam')
print(z)
print(x)
print(y)
print(`x`)
print(`y`)
print(`z`)
```

Имя внутреннего класса начинается с двойного подчеркивания, поэтому он является "частным" (private) и пользователь не сможет получить к нему прямой доступ. Внутренний класс содержит все те же методы, что и класс, который не был бы "одиночкой". Внешний класс при этом управляет созданием внутреннего класса через свой конструктор.

Доступ к внутреннему классу осуществляется через делегирование при помощи метода `__getattr__()`, который пересылает все обращения к внешнему классу на внутренний класс. Из вывода программы можно увидеть, что хотя объекты и разные (т.е. создаются каждый раз), но внутренний класс создается только один раз и используется всеми созданными объектами.

Вариация данной техники через использование классового метода `__new__`:

```
class OnlyOne(object):
    class __OnlyOne:
        def __init__(self):
            self.val = None
        def __str__(self):
            return `self` + self.val
    instance = None
    def __new__(cls): # __new__ always a classmethod
        if not OnlyOne.instance:
            OnlyOne.instance = OnlyOne.__OnlyOne()
        return OnlyOne.instance
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
    def __setattr__(self, name):
        return setattr(self.instance, name)

x = OnlyOne()
x.val = 'sausage'
print(x)
y = OnlyOne()
y.val = 'eggs'
print(y)
z = OnlyOne()
z.val = 'spam'
print(z)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Чаще всего в Singleton'е нас интересует только воможность делить одно состояние между объектами. Т.е. мы можем создать кучу различных объектов, но при этом они будут ссылаться на одно и то же состояние, поэтому изменение одного объекта (точнее его состояния) приведет к аналогичному изменению остальных объектов.

Этого можно добиться, например, поместив в `__dict__` каждого объекта ссылку на какое-то состояния:

```
class Borg:
    _shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_state

class Singleton(Borg):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        Borg.__init__(self)
        self.val = arg
    def __str__(self): return self.val

x = Singleton('sausage')
print(x)
y = Singleton('eggs')
print(y)
z = Singleton('spam')
print(z)
print(x)
print(y)
print(`x`)
print(`y`)
print(`z`)
```

Этот вариант имеет тот же эффект, что и в первом случае, но код получается более изящным. В первом случае вы должны явно реализовать поведение Singleton для каждого вашего класса, в то время как последний вариант спроектирован так, что его легко можно использовать в других классах.

Более простая версия этого варианта использует тот факт, что существует только один экземпляр классовой переменной:

```
class SingleTone(object):
    __instance = None
    def __new__(cls, val):
        if SingleTone.__instance is None:
            SingleTone.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
        SingleTone.__instance.val = val
        return SingleTone.__instance
```

Два других способа определить Singleton: использование обертки и использование метаклассов.

Первый подход может быть реализован через классовый декоратор:

```
class SingletonDecorator:
    def __init__(self,klass):
        self.klass = klass
        self.instance = None
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwds):
        if self.instance == None:
            self.instance = self.klass(*args,**kwds)
        return self.instance

@SingletonDecorator
class foo: pass

x=foo()
y=foo()
z=foo()
x.val = 'sausage'
y.val = 'eggs'
z.val = 'spam'
print(x.val)
print(y.val)
print(z.val)
print(x is y is z)
```

Второй подход использует метаклассы::

```
class SingletonMetaClass(type):
    def __init__(cls,name,bases,dict):
        super(SingletonMetaClass,cls)\
          .__init__(name,bases,dict)
        original_new = cls.__new__
        def my_new(cls,*args,**kwds):
            if cls.instance == None:
                cls.instance = \
                  original_new(cls,*args,**kwds)
            return cls.instance
        cls.instance = None
        cls.__new__ = staticmethod(my_new)

class bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = SingletonMetaClass
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
    def __str__(self):
        return `self` + self.val

x=bar('sausage')
y=bar('eggs')
z=bar('spam')
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
print(x is y is z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как в методе `__new__` у класса создаётся поле `instance`, достаточно просто получить его значение после хотя бы одной инициализации.

```
a = SpriteManager()
b = SpriteManager.instance
print(a is b)  # True
```

Comment: Это, конечно, хорошо, вот только в коде мы не всегда знаем был ли инициализирован класс до этого. Поэтому везде, где используется наш singleton, придется делать проверки на инициализацию. Эти проверки было бы логично реализовать внутри класса, а не снаружи

Comment: @BOPOH Как простое решение, можно просто проинициализировать его сразу, если требуется

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам понравится решение, предложенное в книге Бизли
 Python Cookbook David Beazley and Brian K. Jones
где используется интересный метакласс, унаследовав который, вы получаете синглетон.

Ваш `__init__` будет вызываться один раз.

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__instance = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__instance is None:
            self.__instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.__instance
        else:
            return self.__instance

# Example 
class Spam(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Creating Spam') 


a =Spam()

b = Spam()
print(a is  b)
```

Ваша задача - определить ваш инит в классе, наследующим  Singleton.

И - да! в вики по вашей ссылке уже другой пример :-) из [PEP318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples):

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class MyClass:
```

Как на меня эта реализация самая продуктивная.