# Singleton на Python и del

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблон-одиночка

есть интересный пост [Singleton на  Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443608/singleton-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python)
Добавлю еще две реализации, одна из книги Бизли, другая, из PEP318.

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__instance = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__instance is None:
            self.__instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.__instance
        else:
            return self.__instance

# Example 
class Spam(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, value): 
        print('Creating Spam')
        self.val = value
```

И:

```
#
# PEP318 from
#
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance(*pars, **kpars):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*pars, **kpars)
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.val = value

f = MyClass(3)
f.val
```

А теперь вопрос. Когда я создаю синглетон, инициализируя его каким-то значением, то имеет место следующее.
Если я удаляю синглетон-объект, а потом пытаюсь его создать инициализируя другим значением, поле `f.val` все равно заполняется старым (удаленным из локал, но хранящимся в классе) значением.
Вопрос: Это так надо, или это какой-то нежелательный побочный эффект?
.
Я прбовал такую реализацию, добавив `__del__`,  но он не срабатывает ((

```
class Singleton:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, value):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)     
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, value):
        if hasattr(self, "value"):
            pass
        else:
            self.value = value

    def __del__(self):
        Singleton._instance = None
        # object.__del__(self)
        del self
```

Итого два вопроса:
 1)  можно ли в программе создать синглетон, а потом удалить и создать другой?
 2)  как заставить работать  `__del__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `__del__` вызывается только тогда, когда объект соберет garbage collector. Однако если у вас остались ссылки на объект, то это может произойти далеко не сразу.

Из документации(https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> del x doesn’t directly call x.**del**() — the former decrements the
>   reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x’s
>   reference count reaches zero.

Вместо del, можно создать метод который будет просто очищать instance:

```
class Singleton:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, value):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)     
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, value):
        if hasattr(self, "value"):
            pass
        else:
            self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def clean(cls):
        cls._instance = None

s = Singleton(10)
print(s.value)
Singleton.clean()
s = Singleton(20)
print(s.value)
```

Comment: я хочу воссоздать ситуацию "все экземпляра синглетона удаены и надо создать новый синглетон". Поскольку я не очень с паттернами  -  возможно эта ситуация противоречит самой идее синглетона?

Comment: Можно для этой задачи попробовать использовать WeakValueDictionary(https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620075/5793657). Единственное что придется использовать обертку над интовым значением.

Answer (score 1):

На просторах англоязычного StackOwerflow по подсказке [@Avernial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178429/avernial) нашлось решение моей задачи. Идеально реализованный как на меня Singleton:

```
class SingletonW2(type):
    import weakref
    _instances = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            # This variable declaration is required to force a
            # strong reference on the instance.
            instance = super(SingletonW2, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]


class MockObject(metaclass=SingletonW2):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = args[0]
        print(f"__init__ {args[0]}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MockObject(7)
    print(dict(SingletonW2._instances))
    del m
    print(dict(SingletonW2._instances))
    m = MockObject(9)
    print(dict(SingletonW2._instances))
```